# SLF4J is unable to find a binding (Eclipse Maven project) -- what am I missing?

Tags: slf4j

I have an Eclipse Maven project structured like this:

[image]

log4j.properties content is

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender 
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out 
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Logging code is

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
...
Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyKafkaProducer.class);
logger.warn("WSTART");
```

When trying to execute it, I am getting the infamous message

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

What am I missing?